# Incorrect preprocessor directive error of IF operator

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm writing a GLSL shader using a `#if` preprocessor directive, but I'm always getting the error `incorrect preprocessor directive`.

Here's my code below (just the relevant part):

```
#define thre 20 
float s = get_sample_data(sampling_pos);
#if s > thre
vec4 val = texture(transfer_texture, vec2(s, s));
#endif
```

Comment: I think that you try to use the preprocessor for something that should be done with a regular if(). The value of the variable s cannot be seen by the preprocessor, your code should be if(s>thre) { vec4 val = texture(transfer...... )); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preprocessing is one of the compilation's steps, which occurs before runtime. It just transform the source based on the `#` lines it finds. It doesn't have any clue about variable, which are runtime concepts. At this time, variable has no values, and preprocessor don't even know them.

Knowing that, it is trivial to say that you can't use a variable value in a preprocessor directive.

You can compare a #defined value to a literal constant :

```
#define thre 12
#if thre > 15
    float x  = 1.;
#else
    float x  = -1.;
#endif
```

In glsl, you still can use conditionnal structure, but it is just 'regular' if.

```
if(s>thre){
    // do something
}else{
    // do something else
}
```